# Read specific column from dat-file

Tags: python

I have a .dat-file which I want to read with python and I need to extract one column with measurement values from the .dat-file. When I read the file on with

```
a = open ('example.dat')
b = a.read()
print(b)
a.close
```

the file is read well and it is shown, that she shape is 1, so I have only one row in the file. How do i now extract one, as it looks like in Notepad, column with values that I need and save it to a new array? I am so sorry for this maybe stupid question.

The file looks like this when read with python:

```
YYYY MM DD HH MM SS station_no1 station_no2 ... 4.654 4.324 5.123 ...
```

It contains information on measurement time, stations no., temperature values, etc.

edit: the file looks like this in Notepad. In python it is read as 1 row:

```
YYYY MM DD HH MM SS JulianDay     station1     station2     station3
lat                               46.93842     46.28712     46.82137
lon                               93.94716     93.14256     93.64739
2015 10 01 00 35 30 273.74623     3.4345       3.5686       4.2132
2015 10 01 00 37 00 273.75623     2.5431       3.2143       2.6654
```

I found the solution:

```
f = open('file.dat','r')
data = f.read()
a = data.split('\n',1)[0]
print a
```

Comment: After `b = a.read()`, `c = b.split(" ")` and `print(c)`. It will create array of element separated by space. Probability output may not help you :(

Comment: the problem is, there is not always 1 space as separation. sometimes it is 5 oder more. does this matter?

Comment: More than one space is consecutive delimiters or some value is blank in there?

Comment: It seems that there is more than one space as delimiters

Answer (score 2):

You want to extract only one column from your file which contain only one line? or You want to extract only one column from your file with several line for e.g second column from line 5?

Based on your explanation I'm assuming fields in your file is seperated by "spaces".

```
for line in open("inputfile.txt"):
    columns = line.split(separator) #place counter for line,seperator as space [" "]
        print columns[0] #REPLACE 0 WITH INDEX OF COLUMN YOU WANT TO EXTRACT
```

Comment: For multiple spaces use nothing inside split() method.e.g. line.split() instead of line.split(" ")

Comment: thank you! I am using Spyder as GUI. When reading the file it tells me that the size is 1. When opening the file with Notepad, it looks like the file is structured in 18200 lines/rows and around 40 columns. I would like to read e.g. the 10th column, because this one contains the values I want to extract in a new array.
I tried your suggestions and it works, it prints the xth line of the file. But I need the xth column (the problem is that I dont know the number of the column because the file is read as 1 line only). thanks so much!

Comment: can you provide snippet of your file at least copy of 8-10 lines ,dummy data will also work.Just want to know structure of file in details

Comment: ok first try to print line by line output from your file.After that split each line and access index of your coloum based on that

Comment: try to print content using, "for line in f.read().split('\n'):",is output is still one liner or you or able to seperate out between lines

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
infile = open('input.txt')
for line in infile:
    list = line.split()
    if len(list) >= 10:
        print(list[9])
```

Of course you could save this values to some list o dict.

Comment: I get the Error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

:(

Comment: sorry, I just fixed it!

Comment: so i need to define my file as estatico?

Comment: sorry, that really got out of control, my bad.

Comment: haha no problem. thanks. the problem is, with your code I only get the very last row of the file as a list. But I need the values in the column under station3 listed e.g. :(

Comment: Try printing a line and identify the position in which the column you want is. Now change the index in the last line of my code and should get what you want.

Comment: hmm if I put the position of the temperature value that is in the column (position is 42) I need into `print(list[42])` and put the total number of columns (as I think it is) `if len (list) >= 86` I also only get the very last line of the file as a list :(

Comment: The line `if len (list) >= 86` is only there to filter the first lines, you should try `if len (list) >= 43` if you want to get the 42th element of any row who have it. 

In other words, if you use `if len (list) >= 86` you only print the line with that length and maybe the only line who makes trough this condition is the last.

Comment: okay, unfortunatela this does not work out. i always get the same line as result :(

Answer (score 0):

Just assume that you have a  .txt file named alpha.txt having four columns  0,1,2,3 and you want to read second and third columns, then you can use the following code.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 
#for some specific columns
a,b = np.loadtxt('alpha.txt', unpack=True, usecols = [1,2])
print(a,b)
```

Here a,b are arbitrary variables for reading columns 2,3. We have to choose as many arbitrary variables as the numbers of columns we want to read...

If you want to read all four columns, then there are two ways to do it.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 
#for some specific columns
a,b,c,d = np.loadtxt('alpha.txt', unpack=True, usecols = [0,1,2,3])
print(a,b,c,d)
```

or

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 
#for some specific columns
a,b,c,d = np.loadtxt('alpha.txt', unpack=True)
print(a,b,c,d)
```

The same will be applicable for any .dat file.

Feel free to ask any question...